# Image not getting displayed in datalist

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I am binding images to datalist. Taking the image name from database and giving the path.

**My code is:**

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlImages" runat="server" RepeatColumns="4">
            <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" Height="200px" Width="200px" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("PageName","D:\Sagar\Kinston\WebSite\ScreenMasterImages\{0}.jpg") %>'  runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
```

On .cs page:

```
ds = gc.GetDataToListBinder("select DISTINCT PageOrderID,PageName from ScreenMaster order by PageOrderID")
            dlImages.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
            dlImages.DataBind()
```

I am facing 2 problems :

1. When imagename has space in between it adds %20 in between
   Eg. if imagename is "API Message", it takes it as: "API%20Message"

I tried On this Problem:

Added `ImageUrl='<%#Server.HtmlDecode(Eval("PageName","D:\Sagar\Kinston\WebSite\ScreenMasterImages\{0}.jpg"))'`

But I got error:

```
XML literals and XML properties are not supported in embedded code within ASP.NET
```

1. If there is not space Eg.image name is "Charges" , Then also its not showing it in datalist.

When i ran project, and right clicked on it and view source, then its showing me correct path as:

```
src="D:\Sagar\Kinston\WebSite\ScreenMasterImages\Charges.jpg"
```

but not showing image.

Please help me with above code.

Where i have made mistake?

What else i should add in it?

Comment: You should never use a physical path anyway... please do it with relative instead! Such as `[WEBROOT]\ScreenMasterImages\{0}.jpg` or `~\ScreenMasterImages\{0}jpg`! (for my first example, replace the [WEBROOT] with good information).

Comment: @SimonDugré Thanks but what about actual problems?

Comment: What @SimonDugré mentioned *is* the actual problem. You don't reference images in a web page via drive letter. It needs to be relative to where your web app lives. Try the second example he gave. Also, the web app *needs* to replace the spaces with `%20` - don't decode them.  URLs can't contain spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep it easy and simple.

When trying things like that with URL, to know exactly what to write down, try typing it in your address bar so you'll be able to find the exact syntax needed in order to make it work correctly.

I've done this tons of time and work for me... So you could try something like :

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlImages" runat="server" RepeatColumns="4">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" Height="200px" Width="200px"
               ImageUrl='<%# String.Format("{0}{1}.jpg", "~\ScreenMasterImages\", Server.HtmlDecode(Eval("PageName"))) %>'
               runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```